# How to implement smooth scrolling using both a UIScrollView and an UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiview, uiscrollview

Is is possible to implement smooth scrolling using both a UIScrollView and placing a UITableView at somewhere starting in the middle of the screen? The UIScrollView contentSize is elongated to accomodate the additional height of the UITableView. The UITableView should be able to contain unlimited and unknown number of rows. Scrolling the entire view downwards will cause the upper non-tableview portion to first disappear and then it scrolls down just like a regular table view.

Put it in another way, I'd like to implement a table with some fixed content before the top row. Think of it like a "header area" for the tables, scrolls up and giving way to the entire table rows.

I probably know that I can implement a TableView and programatically make the first row to contain some fixed images. In this way, it will work as expected. But which is easier to implement?

Comment: Does the `tableHeaderView` property not work for what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really don't want to put the table in a scroll view. When the user scrolls on the table it will not move the underlying scrollview so you won't get the effect you are looking for.

Implement viewForHeaderInSection instead and pass in the view you want to display above the first row, or set tableViewHeader.